# Access nested object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I Access 'newsInfo' in this object with moreInfo key?

```
let news = {
  newsId : '1',
  newsTitle : 'Article',
  newsInfo : [
    {
      lessInfo :'new online shop'
    },
    {
      moreInfo : 'create new online shop for merchants'
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: So you have "create new online shop for merchants" and the `news` object? If so, why not just say `news.newsInfo` or `news["newsInfo"]`?

Comment: Task is that i have to grab moreInfo with key and console log it but i dont know how to access it

Comment: have you tried this ```console.log(news.newsInfo[1].moreInfo)``` ?

Comment: This should get you the value of moreInfo: `news.newsInfo[1].moreInfo` or `news["newsInfo"][1]["moreInfo"]`. If not, can you elaborate on what you mean by "grab moreInfo with key"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the dot operator and square brackets to access the second element of the array.

```
const info = news.newsInfo[1].moreInfo;
```

```js
let news = {
  newsId : '1',
  newsTitle : 'Article',
  newsInfo : [
    {
      lessInfo :'new online shop'
    },
    {
      moreInfo : 'create new online shop for merchants'
    }
  ]
};
const info = news.newsInfo[1].moreInfo;
console.log(info);
```

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @Roffulus No problem.